# Picasa Web Api requesting photo in Json, but it always returns Xml data

Tags: json, xml, picasa

When Im trying  to get the list of photos in json format from the following url,It always returns me the xml 
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/sethu.store/?albumid=Keerthi?alt=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your url is wrong.
Try:
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/sethu.store/album/Keerthi?alt=json

Comment: Thank you! How the url is wrong, Im also getting the response for the previous url and as per the document Im using alt=json.

Comment: With reference to the documentation, the format your original url is wrong.  For example, user's id is a number not text.